# How can I get the trailing value in a group

Tags: regex

I have a text and I want to use a regex pattern to put the text into groups.

Here is an example of text I could have:

```
Some text...

<style id=1>Header</style>

Some other text...

<style id=2>
- Bullet 1
- Bullet 2
</style>

Trailing text...
```

Requirements:

1. I may have, or not, text before or after the  tag
2. I want a pattern that returns multiple matches. Ex: In that case, I could have 2 or 3 matches depending on the regex pattern groups.
3. I may have line breaks

I'm currently using this pattern:

```
(?<prefix>[\s\S]*?)<style id=(?<id>[0-9]+)>(?<content>[\s\S]*?)</style>
```

Currently, I have 2 matches using this pattern, which are:

```
[prefix]: Some text...
[id]: 1
[content]: Header

[prefix]: Some other text...
[id]: 2
[content]:
- Bullet 1
- Bullet 2
```

I'm not able to create a group that will catch the "Trailing text...". I tried but when I add a group at the end of my pattern, it returns only one match and its prefix include the first  tag.

Any idea??

Thanks

Comment: By the way, here is a great tool to work with Regex:
http://regexhero.net/tester/

Comment: Your regex ends at `</style>`how can you expect to catch the `Trailing text...` ?

Comment: I know that with this Regex I won't be able to catch it. The point of my question is, how can I do to catch it ;-)

Comment: what comes after the `Trailing text...`?

Comment: The end of the string. The trailing text could be multiline.

Comment: Without a real example I cannot help you. Post the html code you have.

Comment: You could take the example of text I wrote in my question.

Comment: [Don't use regex to parse structured data.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 0):

You can repeat the whole pattern with a `*` and then add something that matches everything.

```
((?<prefix>[\s\S]*?)<style id=(?<id>[0-9]+)>(?<content>[\s\S]*?)</style>)*(?<suffix>[\s\S]*)
```